# How can I remove all non-numeric elements from an array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a String array which contains both integer and non-integer elements, and I need to remove all the non-integer elements of that array.

Now I am only able to remove the non-integer content in a single string, but I need to remove the entire non-integer elements in an array.

My snippet as follows

```
String str = "a12.334tyz.78x";
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
```

Can anyone help me to achieve it?

Comment: You included decimal points in your example. Do you mean integer, or numeric? Should "123.45" be retained? What about "-67" or "+89"?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with some test cases (i.e. pairs of input and expected output).  That will make your requirements much easier to understand, and probably attract better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  achieve it by below code

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d*");
     String [] array=new String[]{"23","33.23","4d","ff"};
     List<String> lst=new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
                if(p.matcher(array[i]).matches()){
                    lst.add(array[i]);
                }
            }
     System.out.println(""+lst);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original code is this:

```
String str = "a12.334tyz.78x";
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
```

First, if you need to remove all non-integer character, you need to change your regex from "[^\d.]" to "[^\d]".
Yours will not remove dots character.

Then, you said:

> Now I am only able to remove the non-integer content in a single
>   string, but I need to remove the entire non-integer elements in an
>   array.

Maybe I'm not getting this right, but isn't just a matter of looping while doing the same thing ?  You didn't show us any code with loops, but perhaps your true problem is reassigning the modified value to the array ?

try this:

```
for(int i=0;i<strArray.length;i++){
    strArray[i] = strArray[i].replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
}
```

MAYBE you were doing something like this ? (this does not work):

```
for(String str: strArray){
    str = str.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
}
```

That doesn't work because the modified string is not reassigned to the array, it is assigned to the new variable 'str'. So this code does not update the value pointed by the array.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Toby. I went to add more details as you suggested, however after re-reading the question, I believe it is rather about "how to loop through an array" than regex. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all the non-integer values form a string you can try the following:

```
public boolean isInt(String s)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        try
        {
            Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
        }catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then you can iterate your array and remove the non-integer elements like this

```
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if(isInt(arr[i]))//remove the element
    }
```

Comment: @ THEVOID : Thank you for the help but i need to remove all the non integer elements in an array.

Comment: @IlavarasanJayaraman Yea sorry about that, try the new version.

Comment: Then iterate through the array elements. Be aware that you can't remove an array element, just change its value. If you need to remove the node that stores the value should use a List

Comment: @MarcoA.Hernandez Yea this is what i did not understand in this question, does the op has an array or just a string.If it is what you propose i will delete my question.

Comment: @theVoid : Thank you but Need to remove all the non - Integer Elements in an array.kindly help.

Comment: @ theVoid : The O/P Must contain only the Integer elements by removing non integer elements.

Comment: @IlavarasanJayaraman I made the method to check if a value is integer or string.I hope i helped man.

Comment: @theVoid:yes and Thank you.But is there any way to remove the particular non integer elements in the iterating loop itself?

Answer (score 0):

replace all numbers - `str = str.replaceAll("\\d", "");`
replace all non-numbers - `str = str.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");`

to do so in an array, iterate over the Array and do the replacment.

Answer (score 0):

If your regex is working correctly, you already solved most of your problem. You only need to use your code in a for loop. You can try the code below:

```
public String[] removeNonIntegersFromArray(String[] array){

    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        String str = array[i];
        if(!str.matches(".*[^\\d]+.*")){
            temp.add(str);  
        }
    }

    String[] result = new String[temp.size()];
    result = (String[]) temp.toArray(new String[temp.size()]);

    return result;
}
```

**Edit:** I refactored the code as it will delete whole array element which has non-integer.

Comment: @ Raptor : Thank you,But I dont want the element, has non integer value to stay in my arrayany more.i need only integer elements in my array.kindly help.

Comment: @IlavarasanJayaraman I edited the code as much as I understood your need. Now it will delete the whole array element which has non-integers in it.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to remove elements from a list than from an array. However, you can stream the elements of the array, remove invalid elements with `flatMap`, and then convert back to an array.

When using `flatMap`, each element in the input can produce zero, one, or many elements in the output, so we map the valid ones to singleton streams containing just that element, and the invalid ones to empty streams, thus removing them from the result.

```
String[] result = Arrays.stream(input)
    .flatMap(a -> Pattern.matches("\\d+", a)?
                Stream.of(a) : Stream.empty())
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea,
Instead of replacing all non-int number, to find all integer and add them to a new string.

```
for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
{
   if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)))
   new_str.append(str.charAt(i));
}
```